# Convert SNMP MIB from web tree form to normal MIB files

Tags: html-parsing, snmp, mib

I have looked for specific MIBs OID I need, but can't find it anywhere. The only ones I find are shoved to web-based [SnmpTree Browser](https://mimir.fcom.ch/wwwbin/snmpnav.pl?oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.2863). Is there a simple method parse and convert the required MIBs from this SnmpTree browser to normal MIB files, for use in SNMP tools or applications?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no such tools. I'm sure you'll be able to find the target MIB file by searching (via google) for particular MIB Object by name.

The web view of MIB file is created based on ASCII SMIv1/v2 MIB file(s). So this is your source and you'll better contact the equipment vendor (Thomson in your case which has been acquired by Technicolor) to obtain MIB files.

Comment: I understand there are no such tool, but I really can't find required MIB. Is there more handy way to create MIB from that web tree use some scripting, rather than manually copy and paste target MIB and it's dependencies into text file?

Comment: Put more details regarding this particular MIB file you're looking for. We might help.